# onChange function for input fields not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

Trying to change the state of input fields but onChange doesn't seem to be working and input fields are disabled (not letting me type)

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        title: '',
        length: '',
        image: '',
        source: '',
        available: '',
        date: '',
        errors: {}
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}

<input value={this.state.length} onChange={this.onChange} type="text" 
    className="form-control" name="email" placeholder="e.g. 3:36" />
```

Comment: Bind the `onChange()` function in the constructor

Comment: this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this); meant to put this in the post, my b, I already binded that shit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things :

Your `setState` function updates a value in the state based on the event's target node name, and here, the name ("email") does not match the value you are getting in your state (length).

The second error is that your `onChange` is not bound to your class, calling `this.setState` will return an error.

You can solve it by changing the value variable in your input :

```
<input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChange} type="text" className="form-control" name="email" placeholder="e.g. 3:36"/>
```

And converting `onChange` to an arrow function (or binding it) :

```
onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

Comment: Thanks fam, should've caught this! Appreciate ya

Answer (score 0):

** UPDATED:
** your main fault, is your are linking your input to a state variable called "length", and the name of the input is "email", they should be the same.

You can make it easier for yourself, you don't need to bind at constructor at all, IF you use arrow functions, so, if your write your function like this:

```
onChange = (e) => {
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

your constructor and state, will be like this:

```
constructor() {
     super();
 this.state = {
    title: '',
    email: '',
    image: '',
    source: '',
    available: '',
    date:'',
    errors: {}
}

}
```

And, in JSX, you still pass your properties the same way, like this:

```
<input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChange} type="text"
        className="form-control" name="email" placeholder="e.g. 3:36" />
```

Full working demo:

[image: Edit 487m15996x]

Comment: Cool thanks, I like this; using arrow function. Although, this still isn't working. The text inputs are still disabled and not letting me type anything... I can't really figure out why this is happening..

Comment: That's because in your code your're linking your input value to : {this.state.length} and the input name is : "name="email" they should be the same, check my updated answer for full working code

Comment: Thanks Fam! Appreciate the help